# jQuery .load stops video embedded in page / reloads whole page

Tags: php, jquery, html, reload

I've a question regarding reloading a div with jQuery-.load. Code:

```
    <h1>Official Live-Stream</h1>
    <object width="560" height="315" data="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x10sbxw"></object>
    </br>
    </br>

    <script>
        (function($)
        {
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $.ajaxSetup(
                {
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#content').hide();
                        $('#loading').show();
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $('#loading').hide();
                        $('#content').show();
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        $('#loading').hide();
                        $('#content').show();
                    }
                });
                var $container = $("#liveracingblog");
                $container.load("../live/addon/addon_ticker.php");
                var refreshId = setInterval(function()
                {
                    $container.load('../live/addon/addon_ticker.php');
                }, 30000);
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>

    <div id="liveracingblog"></div>
```

The problem I have, is that every 30 seconds not only the liveracingblog-div reloads, but the whole page, which makes the video embedded in line #2 stop.

You can observe the problem here: http://www.racingblog.de/racingbloglive/ (the code is part of a `Wordpress` page template, but I don't think that matters)

How can this be fixed?

Comment: have you tried using $.get() instead: `$.get("../live/addon/addon_ticker.php",function(content){$container.html(content);});`  ?

Comment: I changed `$container.load('../live/addon/addon_ticker.php');` to `$.get("../live/addon/addon_ticker.php",function(content){$container.html(conten??t);});` (I think, that is what you meant). Still the same problem...

Comment: ya, that was i mean. If you replace your video with an image, is there still the same issue? This is in purpose of testing if its the flash object which can cause this behaviour.

Comment: Okay, I've replaced the flash object with an image and I can still see the image beeing reloaded every 30 seconds.

Comment: I don't know wordpress but it could be related to it. Maybe try putting your script tag in the head section but honestly, i have no idea on what's going on

Comment: You have several errors popping up in console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.racingblog.de/racingbloglive/recoverscroll.js?_=1371707931648 ________________
Blocked a frame with origin "http://www4.cbox.ws" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.racingblog.de". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. ________________
GET http://www.racingblog.de/racingbloglive/recoverscroll.js?_=1371707961607 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Get rid of those and let's see, what happens.

Comment: From the demo page you link to it looks like you've resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the page and the #content div appears to include the embedded video, which you are hiding and showing in the js. You want to only hide and show the #liveracingblog div

The following change should work:

```
         $.ajaxSetup(
            {
                cache: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#liveracingblog').hide();
                    $('#loading').show();
                },
                complete: function() {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#liveracingblog').show();
                },
                success: function() {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#liveracingblog').show();
                }
            });
```

Also I notice that a huge amount of records are being pulled out of the database every 30 seconds, and because you are using the load() method, any user scrolling down will be returned to the top of this div. I would suggest using forgetting about hiding the divs at all. Instead, replace load() with a $get to return any new records (since the last request), then prepend these new records to the #liveracingblog div.

Either way, good luck with that, and let me know if you want more clarification on this. Adrian